# how to check checklistbox items using datagridview vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, checklistbox

I'm just a beginner for coding and I want to programmatically check items in `checklistbox` using `datagridview`.

Data grid view values are seperated with commas like this `jhon,Metilda,saman,`.

Checklistbox name as `chklistinput` and please help me to solve this ?

'Full coding is here..............................

```
 Private Sub TextBox10_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox10.TextChanged

'this is ok and searching as I want 

    Dim SearchV As String = TextBox10.Text
    SearchV = "%" + TextBox10.Text + "%"

    Me.PassIssuingRecordTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.Database4DataSet.PassIssuingRecord, SearchV)


'But the problem bigins here 

    Dim areasback As String = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value.ToString
    Dim areasback1 As String() = areasback.Split(",")

    For Each x In areasback1
        For i = 0 To areasback.Count - 1

            If chklistInput.Items(i).ToString() = x.ToString() Then
                chklistInput.SetItemChecked(i, False)
            End If

        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the items checked or not checked?  `chklistInput.SetItemChecked(i, False)` sets the item to not checked.  Make it true to check it.  Assuming the number of items in `areasback` is equal to the number of items in the CheckListBox control can be dangerous.

Comment: I tried many different ways but nothing work for me.  Again I tried with "true" statement. but same result. Do I need to change anything from property menu?. Sometimes it is frustrating when cannot complete simple code.  Please help ?

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a stop on the first "for each" line, run the code, when it stops, hover the mouse over the variables to examine the values.

Comment: @larsTech I checked. But the funny thing is values are correct which means values what I need is loading and final result is not coming .

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over `chklistInput.Items.Count - 1` instead of `areasback.Count - 1`

use the following code:

```
Dim areasback As String = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value.ToString
Dim areasback1 As String() = areasback.Split(",")
Dim intCount as integer = 0 

For each str as string in areasback1

    For intCount = 0 To chklistInput.Items.Count - 1

        If chklistInput.Items(intCount).ToString() = str Then
            chklistInput.SetItemChecked(intCount , True)
        End If

    Next

Next

chklistInput.Refresh()
```

**Note:** comparing is case sensitive

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply . I used exact code but nothing happening. May be I'm adding this code in wrong place . Please advice me.

Comment: Look at @LarsTech comment

Comment: @hardi .  Thank you and I tried that also . but the final result is not coming .

Comment: @user3236873 try using `chklistInput.Item(intCount).checked = True` instead of `chklistInput.SetItemChecked(intCount , True)`

Comment: `chklistInput.Item(intCount).checked = True` cannot add `.checked` after intcoun

Comment: @user3236873 when debugging `chklistInput.Items(intCount).ToString() = areasback1(intCount)` condition is met? the problem is in `chklistInput.SetItemChecked(intCount , True)` ??

Comment: @user3236873 Try to add `chklistInput.Refresh()`

Comment: @user3236873 Check it out

Comment: @user3236873 i was wrong you have to loop twice. I edited my answer. The error is that you were looping over `areasback.count` not `chklistInput.Items.Count` so it was looping over characters

Comment: Thank you for the effort but still nothing happens .

Comment: @user3236873 it worked fine with me!! can you provide your complete code. maybe the error from other lines